# Unable to import Postgres Dump - 'invalid input syntax for type' json error

Tags: postgresql

I'm having an issue restoring a dump taken from a Postgres database. The command I'm using is:

`psql -d importantdb -U postgres -f importantdb.dmp -h localhost -p 6432`

And the error I receive is:

```
psql:importantdb.dmp:316814878: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token ""ocr_result" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...0, "distance": 0.0, "timecode": 0.44, "ocr_result
COPY search_frames, line 289143606, column phash_matches: "[{"score": 1500.0, "distance": 0.0, "timecode": 0.04, "ocr_result": {}, "material_id": 1604, "index_..."
```

The dump is about 5TB in size. I've checked the versions, and both the DB the dump was taken from, and the new one, are the same version. The original DB is now gone, so I need to be able to restore this file if possible. Since it was a dev DB it didn't have anything more than a one off dump that was taken at the end of the project.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Is it a one-off problem, i.e. does it work if you delete line 289143606 or does it complain elsewhere then?

Comment: What is Postgres version? What is the data type for the column `phash_matches` JSON or JSONB? That JSON fragment inserts here(Postgres 12) in both `json` and `jsonb`. Do you have only the plain text dump?

Comment: @Bergi - good suggestion, gave it a try and got the same error on line 289143605, so looks like its a consistent problem.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It's PG 11, although I've also tried 12 to see if the more recent version would work. AFAIK, its a JSONB column (I didn't write this particular code). And sadly, its just the plain text dump I've got.

Comment: @MichaelDuffy No, that doesn't look consistent to me. You removed line 606, now you're getting an error from line 605 (the one before)? Either something else is at play here, or you removed the wrong line.

Comment: In a test setup can you  `CREATE` the table and then `COPY`  in say the first ten lines or so of  the data from the dump file? Is there a difference in encoding from the original setup?

Comment: Just noticed this: `""ocr_result" `. The original is, `"ocr_result"`. The second `"` is not being quoted. Wonder if that character is not actually a text double quote?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It is, you can see that in the error message that contains more of the line contents. My guess would be that something is injecting hidden control characters in that position, might be anything from a rotten file, a broken filesystem not being able to handle files that large, a bug in `psql`, or something else.

Comment: @Bergi. Actually no. Example; `select '[{"test": "a", "ocr_result'': {}}]'::jsonb;` where the trailing quotes on `ocr_result` are two single quotes. The error: DETAIL:  Token ""ocr_result': {}}]" is invalid. It drops the second single quote.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply folks, and may thanks for the help so far.

Digging further into the file, this is an example of the lines its struggling with:

`257148165 2020-08-28 08:42:59.448275 /apps/tmp/storage/57/file-1598604179448275673-3713101889932116939-864523902.jpg \N 2020-08-28 08:42:59.548637 2020-08-28 08:42:59.548637 \N t \N 57 \N \N f 3713101889932116939 864523902 [] \N \N \N \N /apps/tmp/storage/57/file-1598604179448275673-3713101889932116939-864523902.jpg \N \N`

I'm guessing it's the `\N` control characters that are breaking it.